# CoInitializeEx() with COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED or COINIT_MULTITHREADED for MS-Word automation using COM C++

Tags: c++, com, office-js, office-addins

I am trying to automate a certain scenario with MS-Word where I want to get the BeforePrint Event to get the filePath while print is initiated. The technology that is needed to get this done is COM C++. I initialize COM library by attaching to word process when it is initiated, by calling CoInitializeEx() with COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED and things work. But when another application is launched which is doing something similar, for example, create pdf from word in Adobe Acrobat DC or any office addin which does something with BeforePrint event, the application/addin errors out with their functionality. My hunch is that something is wrong with the way COM is initialized since if I initialize COM by calling CoInitializeEx() with COINIT_MULTITHREADED everything seems to work fine.
Below are specific questions in this regards:

1. What is different in calling CoInitializeEx() with COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED vs COINIT_MULTITHREADED  that makes it work in this scenario?
2. With most samples online for COM C++ office automation for word, CoInitializeEx() is done with COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED, what is the recommended way and why?
3. Could there be issues for any other application/office addins if my application uses COINIT_MULTITHREADED for CoInitializeEx() instead of COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED?

Links I have already referred but are not conclusive enough:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/threading-support-in-office?view=vs-2019
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objbase/ne-objbase-coinit

Comment: There are whole books written and available about this topic. Sorry, but your questions are way too broad to be answered concisely and correctly here.

Comment: I agree there are many books available and online sample which I have referred and gotten here about this topic. The question is specific around ms-word and BeforePrint event automation with targeted questions on noted observations. Please help suggest/ask questions with more details required to narrow the scope rather. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

When you create a COM object on a STA thread all incoming and outgoing COM calls will be handled from a windows message queue. Event handlers from object the event will also use that message queue and thus event handlers will be called on the same STA thread that created the COM object. However one thing that you cannot do is to make other COM calls to that object from the event handler! (google : COM STA reentrancy).

When you create a COM object on an MTA thread then also events will be handled by MTA threads (from the COM threadpool), and no reentrancy can happen and you can make calls to the object from the event handler. This case is more stable, but if you need to interact with the mainthread (e.g. MainWindow) you have to write some code yourself.

In the end I just prefer MTA's they are less messy even if you have to manage some cross thread communication yourself. But at least it is explicit.